# How to convert a reading to percentage in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I am using [this example](http://developer.wildernesslabs.co/Hardware/Tutorials/Electronics/Part5/Resistive_Sensor_Lab/) on how to use a photoresistor to detect the value of light that the sensor is getting but I want to convert the reading of the resistor to a percentage but I can't use the `map()` function from the Arduino [docs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) but I can implement something similar to it

so I created this simple function

```
float photo_resistor(int pinNum)
{
    float reading = analogRead(pinNum);
    if (reading == 54)
    {
     return 0.0;
    }
    return (reading - 54)/(100/920);

}
```

as in the docs I want to use an output range from 0 to 100 and the minimum reading i got is 54 and the maximum is 974

```
return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
// this becomes (x - 54)*(100 - 0 ) / ( 974 - 54) + 0;
// (x-54)/(100/920);
```

but this does not output a value from on the scale from 0-100

[image]

Comment: your question is about arithmetic, not about Arduino

Comment: think of a basket that can hold 20 apples maximum ... there are 6 apples in the basket ... how full is the basket, expressed in percent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

> ```cpp
> return (reading - 54)/(100/920);
> ```

In C++, `100/920` is zero. This is because, when both operands are
integers, the division operator performs an integer division. You can
overcome this problem by making sure that at least one of the operands
is a floating point number. For instance, `100.0/920` is roughly 0.1087.

However, your division is backwards. You probably mean

```cpp
return (reading - 54) * (100.0/920);
```

Comment: I'd use `return max(0.0, min(100.0, (reading-54.0)*(100.0/920)));` -- this makes sure that no values outside the range 0.0 .. 100.0 are ever returned, even when another photoresistor with slightly different tolerances is being used.